# Elastic Beanstalk is wrongly deploying environment with Python 2.7 rather than 3.7

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

After running `eb init` I chose an environment with Python 3.7 and AL 2. This is the config file that was generated:

```
branch-defaults:
  default:
    environment: django-env
    group_suffix: null
global:
  application_name: dashboard
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: aws-eb
  default_platform: Python 3.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2
  default_region: us-west-2
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: eb-cli
  repository: null
  sc: null
  workspace_type: Application
```

So clearly I'm supposed to have python 3.7 in the EC 2 instance, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

When I SSH into the instance and run `python`, the instance's default is 2.7. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `python3` instead of `python`.

```
python3 -V
Python 3.7.6
```

but

```
python -V
Python 2.7.16
```